# Database setup for activity logging

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I'm currently working on an application, which requires detection of activity within the past 12 hours (divided into 10 minute intervals, i.e. 6 times an hour). My initial thought has been to do a cronjob every 10 minutes to detect and accumulate activity level (rows) from a table within the past 10 minutes, and then insert these into a new table, which collects and updates the activity level for e.g. 1.20 (from current timestamp).

Though I'm struggling in figuring out the logic of "pushing" (in need of a better word) all other values to next value within the table. E.g. 1 hour and 20 minutes ago, should then be "pushed" to 1 hour and 30 minutes ago etc.

I realize that my thoughts as to the setup is limited to my understanding of PHP/MySQL and use of same, but am open to other setups such as NodeJS/MongoDB if that seems more flexible and feasible. The output should be a JSON file, showing the activity level for each hour divided into 10 minutes for the past 12 hours.

Would love some thoughts/feedback as to approach and way to handle this. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with MySQL's Event Scheduler?

Comment: @N.B. Actually not. Looked it up and looks promising. As I understand it, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I'd then schedule an event as recurring every 10 minutes counting number of rows (activity) and storing these inside a table instead of doing a cron job. Though I struggle to see how it will solve the challenge of pushing values for each event run. I.e. pushing from 10 minutes from now to 20 minutes from now and so on. Cheers.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, your task is that you need to collect data from MySQL based on time intervals and store the result somewhere else. Instead of having a cron job that triggers a script, you can have MySQL execute required queries and store the result in the table that you read using your application. However, you're talking about "pushing" so I'm kind of lost there. The point of my comment was to steer you away from cron so you can do all database-related work within the db itself. Since you have further problems, maybe expand the question with additional details?